# AVPlayer Full Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer

i'm using AVPlayer in my apps instead MPMoviePlayerController since i want to put the player as sublayer.
However i need control like play, pause, search, and full screen. How do i get that button in AVPlayer?
This is how i put the player:

```
    AVURLAsset *avasset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:URL1 options:nil];

    AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:avasset];
    player = [[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item]retain];

    playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
    float x = size.width/2.0-187.0;
    float y = size.height/2.0 - 125.0;

    playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 474, 320);
    [playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    [player play];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to provide your own buttons.

For [`play`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/play) and [`pause`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/pause) there are direct API's in AVPlayer.

For full screen… well… you know where you are drawing: you just need to size your UIWindow and corresponding UIView & layer to be full size.

For search, you do have methods like [`seekToTime:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/seekToTime:)

Answer (score 6):

For future reference iOS 8 AVKit has the AVPlayerViewController class available that will wrap a AVPlayer and has the standard MPMoviePlayerController class controls.

[AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerViewController/videoGravity)

```
AVPlayerViewController * filePlayerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController alloc];
//Show the controls
filePlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = true;
AVPlayer * filePlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.videoFile.localURL]];
filePlayerViewController.player = self.filePlayer;
```